Partial Hessian vibrational analysis (PHVA) of adsorption in MOFs
I have been probing acid sites in metal-organic frameworks (MOFs) by performing the partial Hessian vibrational analysis (PHVA) which provides information about characteristic vibrational modes that change upon adsorption. The calculations were done in Quantum Espresso and the vibrational toolkit of the ASE. The problem arises when I try to estimate the thermochemistry of the process. I defined the enthalpy of adsorption as:
$$
\Delta H_{ads} = H^{ads} - H^{gas} - E^{SC}
$$
where $H^{ads}$ is the enthalpy of an adsorbed species (within the PHVA approximation), $H^{gas}$ is the enthalpy of the gas-phase species, and $E^{SC}$ is the electronic energy of an empty supercell of MOF. In the case of $H^{gas}$, I applied the ideal gas approximation in which we consider the rotational, translational, and vibrational contributions separately.
The problem occurs in the case of $H^{ads}$ for which I apply the harmonic limit. In this approach, we consider only the vibrational modes without the translational and rotational movements. But as I understood, all 3N modes are considered vibrational, not the standard 3N-6. In some cases, I observe a huge shift of the first 6 modes (from 2-3 $cm^{-1}$ in the case of isolated species to 100-200 $cm^{-1}$ in the case of adsorbed one). In that case, should I use all 3N modes to calculate the zero-point energy and the extrapolation to finite temperature? What if in some instances I do not observe such great shifts and these modes are within 20-60 $cm^{-1}$? Can I arbitrarily count only those that are, let's say, above 50 $cm^{-1}$ and discard anything below this threshold?
I found some literature on the adsorption in zeolites (an exhaustive example 1) where they distinguish mobile and immobile adsorbate but it is still unclear to me. As I understood, there are two crucial problems: (1) the loss of the DOFs upon adsorption and (2) the PHVA approach itself. I found some papers that suggest the PHVA requires treating all 3N modes as vibrations. Is it true?

+1. Welcome to our community!
